# Docker swarm join linux container Error - remote CA does not match fingerprint

Tags: docker, containers, devops, docker-swarm

**Start docker swarm :**
docker swarm init --advertise-addr

**Join docker swarm:**
docker swarm join --token  :2377

I am using Windows 10,
it is working fine with Windows container mode, but gives below error in Linux container mode.

**Error:**

Error response from daemon: remote CA does not match fingerprint. Expected: 91030413f17ec7c023a2a796ee05a024915080ca8dfd646a597c7e966f667df6

**Docker swarm manager host command: docker node ls**

```
ID                            HOSTNAME            STATUS              AVAILABILITY        MANAGER STATUS
2zf1l2o7sl2a1qka55s2vi77x *   moby                Ready               Active              Leader
```

Host name is **moby**, when running in Windows container mode it gives machine host correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Your token is wrong.

You can get a worker token in the manager node:

```
docker swarm join-token -q worker
```

It works for me.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/swarm_join/